# Using functions in header files

Tags: arduino-ide, error, functions, header

I want to include a function in my sketch I moved to a .h file.

I did it as follows:

My code:

```
#include "header.h"

void setup() {
  fct();
}

void loop() {

}
```

My header:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#ifndef MYHELPERS_H
#define MYHELPERS_H

void fct() {
// stuff
}

#endif
```

The same process seems to work for variables but the IDE says this function in not declared in this scope...

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks guys!

Comment: for me it compiles. do you have the header file as tab in IDE?

Comment: Where exactly does your header file lie? In the same folder as the main sketch? Or in the libraries folder?

Comment: This is not the way you separate your project in modules. In a header file you declare what your module offers _publically_. The implementation goes into another C++ file and this will be compiled separately. -- Please get a good book on basic C++ and/or Arduino programming and read it. This issue is far too broad to be answered in a SE/Arduino question.

Comment: This header file was created with the new file button in the Arduino editor and it resides in the same folder as the main sketch.

Comment: File->New, creates a new sketch

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution somewhere else on internet...

This portion:

```
#ifndef MYHELPERS_H
#define MYHELPERS_H
```

Was not written correctly... "MYHELPERS_H" should've been replaced by the name of my file. Now it works just fine.

Comment: there is no relation between the include guard macro name and the name of the file. this answer is wrong.

Comment: It's weird but it fixed my problem

Comment: Maybe the guard macro name has to be the name using in the #include of the main sketch but it works now I have done this

Comment: no. #include takes a file name. and it doesn't care about the content of the file

Comment: Anyway, it worked

Comment: so change it back and you see it will still work

Comment: I'm on a work trip right now and my pc is home

Comment: Sorry Spyro, this answer makes absolutely no sense - downvoted.